# Suppressing readOGR Messages in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, rgdal

I wonder how to suppress `readOGR` error messages in `knitr`. My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
<< Test >>=
library(rgdal)
dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
setwd(dsn)
cities <- readOGR(dsn=dsn, layer="cities")
@ 
\end{document}
```

The function `readOGR` gives the message like this:

```
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "/home/asd/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rgdal/vectors", layer: "cities"
with 606 features
It has 4 fields
```

But I want to suppress this message. I tried `message=FALSE`, but it did not work for me.

**Edited**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggmap_2.4       mapproj_1.2-2   maps_2.3-9      leaflet_1.0.0   rgeos_0.3-11    rgdal_1.0-4    
 [7] maptools_0.8-36 sp_1.1-1        Hmisc_3.16-0    Formula_1.2-1   survival_2.38-2 lattice_0.20-31
[13] psych_1.5.4     ggbiplot_0.55   plyr_1.8.3      gplots_2.17.0   rsm_2.7-2       scales_0.2.5   
[19] ggplot2_1.0.1   xtable_1.7-4    highr_0.5       knitr_1.10.12   brew_1.0-6      stringr_1.0.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] RColorBrewer_1.1-2   jsonlite_0.9.16      reshape2_1.4.1       cluster_2.0.2        rstudioapi_0.3.1    
 [6] magrittr_1.5         acepack_1.3-3.3      gtable_0.1.2         htmltools_0.2.6      splines_3.2.1       
[11] dplyr_0.4.2          KernSmooth_2.23-14   htmlwidgets_0.5      gridExtra_0.9.1      R6_2.0.1            
[16] digest_0.6.8         colorspace_1.2-6     proto_0.3-10         stringi_0.5-2        yaml_2.1.13         
[21] lazyeval_0.1.10.9000 evaluate_0.7         labeling_0.3         RJSONIO_1.3-0        gdata_2.16.1        
[26] rpart_4.1-9          munsell_0.4.2        DBI_0.3.1            Rcpp_0.11.6          RgoogleMaps_1.2.0.7 
[31] png_0.1-7            MASS_7.3-41          parallel_3.2.1       assertthat_0.1       rjson_0.2.15        
[36] caTools_1.17.1       gtools_3.5.0         jpeg_0.1-8           latticeExtra_0.6-26  foreign_0.8-63      
[41] bitops_1.0-6         nnet_7.3-9           geosphere_1.3-13     formatR_1.2          mnormt_1.5-3
```

Comment: did you try `verbose=FALSE` in `readOGR`?

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr for your helpful comment. Would you mind to change your comment to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `verbose=FALSE` to the `readOGR` call to suppress the messages (which are helpful during an interactive session but are cruft when in scripts or notebooks).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<<Test, message=FALSE, results='hide', echo=FALSE>>=
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it does not work.

Comment: Please post: `library("knitr"); sessionInfo()`. And it is always a good idea to say what you have tried before, results='hide' was not among it.

Comment: I;m still getting messages printed with echo=F, not sure if anyone else has any ideas?